# Run script after inserting data from QR code

Tags: google-apps-script, qr-code

We use the [scan to sheet app](http://Scan%20to%20Sheets%20by%20Jibran%20Khalil%20https://apps.apple.com/be/app/scan-to-sheets/id1434948420) to add data to a spreadsheet and we build an app script to print the sheet.
Now we want the script to run if we add the data with the app.

Sadly this doesn't work with a simple onEdit() function (I think because triggers don't react on API request)

The script needs to run directly when we scan the QR code, one minute timer is no option.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me.  Where is your Apps Script Code?

Comment: ]onEdit trigger reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedite)

Answer (score 0):

### If you spreadsheet is populated with a Formula (e.g. IMPORTRANGE), an installable `onChange` trigger will work for you.